# How to position a background image without background-position property

Tags: css

In the menu in this page(blog.prco.com) I put a background image in the hover of the elements, but for the origin of the element, and the target of background-position, the dot is moving to the final position.

The question is, how can I center the image under the element without background-position property. I want a fixed image.

Please only css, I can't change the html, because this site is on wordpress

Thank you

Comment: You can use `:after` selector with your background in order to position your dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution with the `:after` selector :

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8y8amns/)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
li a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 6px;
  height: 5px;
  background: url(http://blog.prco.com/wp-content/themes/annina/images/dotCo.png) center bottom no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
li a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-menu1" class="menu nav-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-60" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-60"><a href="http://blog.prco.com/blog/category/london/">LONDON</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-56"><a href="http://blog.prco.com/blog/category/paris/">PARIS</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-57"><a href="http://blog.prco.com/blog/category/munich/">MUNICH</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-58"><a href="http://blog.prco.com/blog/category/moscow/">MOSCOW</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-59"><a href="http://blog.prco.com/blog/category/dubai/">DUBAI</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-61" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-61"><a href="http://blog.prco.com/blog/category/new-york/">NEW YORK</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-62"><a href="http://blog.prco.com/blog/category/milan/">MILAN</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a fixed image, use "background-attachment" with the atribute "fixed".
For example:

```
div {
  background-image: url("images/imagen_pequena.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```